# Why am I allowed to run a CUDA kernel with more blocks than my GPU's CUDA core count?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

## Comments / Notes

- Can I have more thread blocks than the maximum number of CUDA cores?
- How does warp size relate to what I am doing?

## Begin

I am running a cuda program using the following code to launch cuda kernels:

```
cuda_kernel_func<<<960, 1>>> (... arguments ...)
```

I thought this would be the limit of what I would be allowed to do, as I have a GTX670MX graphics processor on a laptop, which according to Nvidia's website has 960 CUDA cores.

So I tried changing `960` to `961` assuming that the program would crash. It did not...

What's going on here?

This is the output of `deviceQuery`:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 670MX"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 3072 MBytes (3221028864 bytes)
  ( 5) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     960 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            601 MHz (0.60 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1400 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              192-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 393216 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 670MX
Result = PASS
```

I am not sure how to interpret this information. It says here "960 CUDA cores", but then "2048 threads per multiprocessor" and "1024 threads per block".

I am slightly confused about what these things mean, and therefore what the limitations of the cuda_kernel_func<<<..., ...>>> arguments are. (And how to get the maximum performance out of my device.)

I guess you could also interpret this question as "What do all the statistics about my device mean." For example, what actually is a CUDA core / thread / multiprocessor / texture dimension size?

Comment: This question could easily be answered by reading the [first five pages](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#introduction) of the CUDA programming guide

Comment: Thanks that's not a helpful comment, of course I've read this document.

Comment: @talonmies All copies of it should be removed from the internet anyway - it's a less than useless resource.

Comment: Seriously, look at figure 5. It is the precise answer to your question. You don't even need to read. Just look at it

Comment: @talonmies How does Figure 5 help in any way shape or form?

Comment: You realise that you ran with 960 blocks of 1 thread, right?

Comment: @user3728501: You asked "Can I have more thread blocks than the maximum number of CUDA cores?". Figure 5 is the answer to that question.

Comment: @Gilles No I didn't realize that but I do now.

Comment: @talonmies So the answer is yes, but it will be slow?

Comment: You know, you should really rephrase the body of your question. I think if you'd have asked it differently (e.g. not put comments at the beginning) you would not have gotten 3 downvotes.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for the advice - to be honest I am a little beyond caring now. Why should it matter how questions are structured? If there's useful info one should know before reading the main body of a question - why not put it there?

Comment: @user3728501: It matters for people who read them. And a question is like a small story: "I was walking in the park one day and this-or-that happened to me, blah blah blah. What should I do?"  afterwards you want to add comments, notes, etc. Otherwise it's, well, annoying to read. Also, in your case, the comments are out-of-context for someone who hasn't already gone through the rest of your question.

Comment: @einpoklum I disagree.

Comment: @user3728501: Maybe, but it's the people who read your question that you're addressing, not your own preferences...

Answer (score 3):

It didn't crash because the number of 'CUDA cores' has nothing to do with the number of blocks. Not all blocks necessarily execute in parallel. CUDA just schedules some of your blocks after others, returning after all block executions have taken place.

You see, NVIDIA is misstating the number of cores in its GPUs, so as to make for a simpler comparison with single-threaded non-vectorized CPU execution. Your GPU actually [has 6 cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_series#GeForce_600_.286xx.29_series) in the [proper sense of the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor); but each of these can execute a lot of instructions in parallel on a lot of data. Note that the bona-fide cores on a Kepler GPUs are called "SMx"es (and are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_series#Next_Generation_Streaming_Multiprocessor_.28SMX.29) briefly).

So:

> [Number of actual cores] x [max number of instructions a single core can execute in parallel] = [Number of "CUDA cores"]

e.g. 6 x 160 = 960 for your card.

Even this is a rough description of things, and what happens within an SMx doesn't always allow us to execute 160 instructions in parallel per cycle. For example, when each block has only 1 thread, that number goes down by a factor of 32 (!)

Thus even if you use 960 rather than 961 blocks, your execution isn't as well-parallelized as you would hope. And - you should really use more threads per block to utilize a GPU's capabilities for parallel execution. More importantly, you should find a good book on CUDA/GPU programming.

Comment: @user3728501: Answer rewritten, I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Okay thanks - I understand that quite well... Except I think I have "5 * 192 CUDA cores" - but this is just a matter of detail.

Comment: By the way I made an edit because I think you missed a word out - if I edited this incorrectly please feel free to change it again.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer:

Blocks do not all execute at the same time. Some blocks may finish before others have even started. The GPU takes does X amount of blocks at a time, finishes those, grabs more blocks, and continues until all blocks are finished.

Aside: This is why thread_sync only synchronizes threads within a block, and not within the whole kernel.